# Is there a way to bind okhttp client with specific network type?

Tags: android, retrofit, wifi, vpn, okhttp

I have a project where I use Retrofit and RxJava for my network calls and Dagger2 for dependency injection.

I have two Retrofit instances and two different RestClients because I want to communicate with two interfaces, one over WiFi and one over VPN (with https).

The problem is that when I close the WiFi of the phone (and then re-open it) the Android somehow chooses the VPN interface in opposition to the WiFi, so the calls that needed to be sent over WiFi end with TimeoutException.

Is there a way to bind my two different okhttpclients with specific network type (e.g. define the transport type or the capabilities)?

Thank you!